# Mercurial, Forget files forever

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Is it possible in mercurial to ignore changes within an entire directory.

For example I would like mercurial to not tell me that changes to the "class" directory have occurred since I don't want to version control the *.class files for my project.

Comment: There are already several questions on stackoverflow about this, in addition to google hits for 'Mercurial ignore'.  How did you search?

Comment: I had a misunderstanding of how hg forget functioned and was searching based on that.  Searching for mercurial ignore turns up everything I want.  thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to set up a rule in your [.hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) file.

There's a pretty good explanation [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore).

Comment: excellent, I feel silly for not being able to find that on my own.

Thanks!